# SharePoint with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, sharepoint, internet-explorer-11

I'm looking answers for this but I cant't find them.

I have a SharePoint project, I'm using MVC, Linq, Javascript, C# and JQuery, some additional libraries, it  is all good in Chrome but when I open IE11 is not working right and I saw some errors that didn't appear in Chrome, do someone know what is this about?[image]

Comment: This issue can be related to the same-origin policy. Are you using different protocols in your requests like from HTTPS to HTTP? I suggest you try to use HTTPS only. The request violates a policy decision, or the origin is not a valid scheme/host/port tuple (this can happen if the origin uses the file: or data: scheme, for example). For example, the user may have their browser configured to deny permission to persist data for the specified origin. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Definition_of_an_origin

Comment: thnks for your time, actually your right, in addition Ecma6 is not fully compatible.

Comment: I suggest you mark the helpful suggestions as an answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be related to the same-origin policy. Are you using different protocols in your requests like from HTTPS to HTTP? I suggest you try to use HTTPS only. The request violates a policy decision, or the origin is not a valid scheme/host/port tuple (this can happen if the origin uses the file: or data: scheme, for example). For example, the user may have their browser configured to deny permission to persist data for the specified origin.

Ref:

[same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Definition_of_an_origin)